# What are the principles of a well structured log (file)

Tags: logging, format

There are a lot of different log file formats out there independent from language, being a server a desktop application.

Here some examples:

desktop app:

```
[main] INFO  MyApp  - Entering application.
[main] DEBUG com.foo.Bar  - Did it again!
[main] INFO  MyApp  - Exiting application.
```

access log:

```
127.0.0.1 - frank [10/Oct/2000:13:55:36 -0700] "GET /apache_pb.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 2326
```

json:

```
{
       "message" => "Dec 23 14:30:01 louis CRON[619]: (www-data) CMD (php /usr/share/cacti/site/poller.php >/dev/null 2>/var/log/cacti/poller-error.log)",
       "@timestamp" => "2013-12-23T22:30:01.000Z",
       "@version" => "1",
        ...
}
```

What are fundamental principles a well structured log (file) should follow?

- what should it contain?
- what should it not contain?

Comment: some interesting answers.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/927328/what-should-an-application-log-ideally-contain   http://www.slideshare.net/anton_chuvakin/application-logging-good-bad-ugly-beautiful-presentation

Answer (score 0):

should contains:
logger timestamp, error level, Login UserInfo , Ip address, class-Method info( name and line number), exception message and stack track if needed, error codes

suggestions:  always try to mask sensitive info, make sure to roll the logs by x days or by size of the file.

should not display: ssn, password, secret answers, bank account numbers etc..